# Java Blowfish CBC Decryption javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted

Tags: java, encryption, blowfish

I am trying to decrypt bytes using the Blowfish CBC algorithm. The encrypted data is hex encoded.

```
String decrypt(String skey, String encryptedData) {

  byte[] IV = hexStringToByteArray("0001020304050607");
  byte[] data = hexStringToByteArray(encryptedData);

  try {
      SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(skey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Blowfish");
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec(IV));
      byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
      return bytesToHex(decrypted);
  } catch (Exception e) {

      return e.toString();
  }
}
```

It returns `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted, null` (the errors are returned for debugging/testing purproses). Thank you.

Comment: `BadPaddingExceptions`, as probably hundreds of Q/A's testify on this site alone, are commonly due to the wrong key or - less likely - wrong IV (if the message < 1 block) or altered ciphertext. Note that a password is not the same thing as a key; secret keys generally are not transmitted through a `String`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import static javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.*;

public class BlowFishTest {

    private String encrypt(String skey, String unencryptedData) {
        byte[] IV = hexStringToByteArray("0001020304050607");
        byte[] data = hexStringToByteArray(unencryptedData);
        try {
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(skey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Blowfish");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,
                    new javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec(IV));
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
            return bytesToHex(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return e.toString();
        }
    }

    private String decrypt(String skey, String encryptedData) {

        byte[] IV = hexStringToByteArray("0001020304050607");
        byte[] data = hexStringToByteArray(encryptedData);

        try {
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(skey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Blowfish");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec(IV));
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
            return bytesToHex(decrypted);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            return e.toString();
        }
    }

    public byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String encryptedData) {
        return parseHexBinary(encryptedData);
    }

    public String bytesToHex(byte[] decrypted) {
        return printHexBinary(decrypted);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myKey = "mySecret";
        String message = "myTestingString";
        BlowFishTest blowFishTest = new BlowFishTest();
        String myHexString = blowFishTest.bytesToHex(message.getBytes());
        String encryptedHex = blowFishTest.encrypt(myKey, myHexString);
        String unencryptedHex = blowFishTest.decrypt(myKey, encryptedHex);
        System.out.println(new String(blowFishTest.hexStringToByteArray(unencryptedHex)).equals(message));
    }
}
```

```
true
```

Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce the issue with the codes you have provided. You may need to check your input, which is unencryptedData and the hexStringToByteArray and bytesToHex methods.

Answer (score -1):

My mistake. It should be `Blowfish/CBC/NoPadding`